# Questions about upgrading from neo4j 2.2.x to 3.x

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to upgrade from neo4j `2.2.x` to `3.x`, and have a couple of questions.

1. Were `org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations` and `org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Caches` removed from `3.x`?
2. Does `dbms.directories.data`  correspond to `org.neo4j.server.database.location`?

Comment: can you split this into two question, please?

Comment: Answer to (2) which I'll move to a proper answer if the question gets split.

No: the two settings do not directly correspond. In Neo4j 3.0 the management of the internal structure of the `data`directory is controlled entirely by Neo4j. It is no longer possible to specify the path of an individual database.

To migrate from 2.x to 3.x you should import your database from the old location as described in http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

At least about (1): Methods from `GlobalGraphOperations` moved into `GraphDatabaseService`. `Caches` were removed in 2.3 due to removal of the object cache.